# A sum of fractional parts.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, problem-solving, fractional-part

I am looking to evaluate the sum $$\sum_{1\leq k\leq mn}\left\{ \frac{k}{m}\right\} \left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\} .$$

Using matlab, and experimenting around, it seems to be $\frac{(m-1)(n-1)}{4}$ when $m,n$ are relatively prime.  How can we prove this, and what about the case where they are not relatively prime?

**Conjecture:**  Numerically, it seems that for any $m,n$ we have $$\sum_{1\leq k\leq mn}\left\{ \frac{k}{m}\right\} \left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\} =\frac{(m-1)(n-1)}{4}+C(\gcd(m,n))$$
where $C(\gcd(m,n))$ is some constant depending only on the $\gcd(m,n)$.

**Additionally:**  Can we sum this even when it is not a complete interval? Suppose that $0<a<b<mn,$ do we have an exact form for $$\sum_{a\leq k\leq b}\left\{ \frac{k}{m}\right\} \left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\}.$$

**Remark:** In the one variable case we have $$\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\} =\frac{n-1}{2}$$ the sum over an interval $a,b$ has an explicit form.

Comment: When $m=n$ your sum seems to be $(n-1)(2n-1)/6$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: That seems to be right since we are counting the interval $[1,n]$ exactly $n$ times.  That is we have $$\sum_{1\leq k\leq n^2}\left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\}^2=n\sum_{1\leq k\leq n-1}\frac{k^2}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2=\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}.$$

Comment: More generally, we could ask about $$\sum_{k=0}^{f-1}\left\{a_1\frac{k}{f}\right\}\cdots\left\{a_r\frac{k}{f}\right\}.$$ This case corresponds to $f=mn,~r=2;~~a_1=m,~a_2=n$.

Comment: @anon: I think your idea almost gives the general solution I am looking for.  We know that for _some_ choices of $k$ modulo $mn$ we have $$\left(\sum_{1\leq k\leq m}\left\{ \frac{k}{m}\right\} \right)\left(\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\} \right)=\sum_{k\text{ mod }mn}\left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\} \left\{ \frac{k}{m}\right\}  $$ but then we just need to remove duplicates and such so that the right hand side is my desired sum above.  The left hand side is easily calculated to be $\frac{(m-1)(n-1)}{4}$, so if we can remove and calculate the additional terms, this gives the result.

Comment: I am not yet convinced that enough "numerical evidence" has been looked at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's call your sum $f(m,n)$.  The ordinary generating function of $f(\cdot,n)$ appears to be 
of the form $$g(z,n) = \frac{z^2 p_n(z)}{6 (1-z)(1-z^n)}$$ where $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ (except for $n=2$ where it has degree $0$):
$$\eqalign{
p_{{2}}&=3\cr
p_{{3}}&=-{z}^{2}+7\,z+3\cr
p_{{4}}&=-3\,{z}^{3}+12\,{z}^{2}+3\,z+6\cr
p_{{5}}&=-6\,{z}^{4}+18\,{z}^{3}+6\,{z}^{2}+6\,z+6\cr
p_{{6}}&=-10\,{z}^{5}+25\,{z}^{4}+6\,{z}^{3}+5\,{z}^{2}+10\,z+9\cr
p_{{7}}&=-15\,{z}^{6}+33\,{z}^{5}+9\,{z}^{4}+9\,{z}^{3}+9\,{z}^{2}+9\,z
+9\cr
p_{{8}}&=-21\,{z}^{7}+42\,{z}^{6}+9\,{z}^{5}+12\,{z}^{4}+3\,{z}^{3}+18
\,{z}^{2}+9\,z+12\cr
p_{{9}}&=-28\,{z}^{8}+52\,{z}^{7}+12\,{z}^{6}+8\,{z}^{5}+16\,{z}^{4}+12
\,{z}^{3}+8\,{z}^{2}+16\,z+12\cr
p_{{10}}&=-36\,{z}^{9}+63\,{z}^{8}+12\,{z}^{7}+15\,{z}^{6}+12\,{z}^{5}+
3\,{z}^{4}+24\,{z}^{3}+15\,{z}^{2}+12\,z+15\cr
p_{{11}}&=-45\,{z}^{10}+75\,{z}^{9}+15\,{z}^{8}+15\,{z}^{7}+15\,{z}^{6}
+15\,{z}^{5}+15\,{z}^{4}+15\,{z}^{3}+15\,{z}^{2}+15\,z+15\cr
p_{{12}}&=-55\,{z}^{11}+88\,{z}^{10}+15\,{z}^{9}+14\,{z}^{8}+13\,{z}^{7
}+24\,{z}^{6}-{z}^{5}+34\,{z}^{4}+9\,{z}^{3}+20\,{z}^{2}+19\,z+18\cr}$$

EDIT: This seems to come from the fact that $$f(m+n,n) - f(m,n) =\frac{n^2-n}{4}$$
for all $m$ and $n$.

EDIT: Let $g(m,n) = f(m,n) - \dfrac{(m-1)(n-1)}{4}$.  From $f(m+n,n) - f(m,n) = \dfrac{n^2-n}{4}$ we get $g(m+n,n) = g(m,n)$.  By following the Euclidean algorithm, we get $$g(m,n) = g(d,d) = \dfrac{(d-1)(2d-1)}{6} - \dfrac{(d-1)^2}{4} = \frac{d^2-1}{12}$$ where $d = \gcd(m,n)$.  That is,
$$ f(m,n) = \frac{\gcd(m,n)^2-1}{12} + \dfrac{(m-1)(n-1)}{4} $$

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Analysis of a small example $m=4, n=6$ with $d=\mathrm{gcd}(4,6)=2$ indicates how to derive the general case.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leq k\leq 24}&\left\{\frac{k}{4}\right\}\left\{\frac{k}{6}\right\}\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{6}
+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{6}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{0}{6}}\\
&\,\,\qquad\color{blue}{+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{6}
+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{6}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{0}{6}}\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{6}
+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{6}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{0}{6}\\
&\qquad+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{6}
+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{6}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{0}{6}\\
&=2\left(\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\color{blue}{+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{6}}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{6}
\color{blue}{+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{6}}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\color{blue}{+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{0}{6}}\right.\\
&\qquad\left.+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\color{blue}{+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{6}}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{6}
\color{blue}{+\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{6}}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\color{blue}{+\frac{0}{4}\cdot\frac{0}{6}}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=2\left(\frac{0}{4}+\frac{2}{4}\right)\left(\frac{0}{6}+\frac{2}{6}+\frac{4}{6}\right)
+2\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{3}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Generalising these steps we obtain for non-negative integers $m,n$ and $d=\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)$
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq k\leq mn}}\color{blue}{\left\{\frac{k}{m}\right\}\left\{\frac{k}{n}\right\}}\\
> &\quad=d\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{mn}{d}}\left\{\frac{k}{m}\right\}\left\{\frac{k}{n}\right\}\tag{3}\\
> &\quad=d\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\sum_{p=0}^{\frac{m}{d}-1}\frac{j+pd}{m}\right)
> \left(\sum_{q=0}^{\frac{n}{d}-1}\frac{j+qd}{n}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &\quad=d\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\frac{m}{d}\cdot\frac{j}{m}+\frac{d}{m}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{m}{d}-1\right)\frac{m}{d}\right)
> \left(\frac{n}{d}\cdot\frac{j}{n}+\frac{d}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n}{d}-1\right)\frac{n}{d}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &\quad=d\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\frac{j}{d}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{m}{d}-1\right)\right)
> \left(\frac{j}{d}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n}{d}-1\right)\right)\\
> &\quad=d\left(\frac{1}{d^2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}(d-1)d(2d-1)
> +\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{m}{d}-1\right)\frac{1}{d}\cdot\frac{1}{2}(d-1)d\right.\\
> &\qquad\left.+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{n}{d}-1\right)\frac{1}{d}\cdot\frac{1}{2}(d-1)d
> +\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{m}{d}-1\right)\left(\frac{n}{d}-1\right)\right)\tag{6}\\
> &\quad=\frac{1}{6}(d-1)(2d-1)+\frac{1}{4}(m-d)(d-1)\\
> &\qquad +\frac{1}{4}(n-d)(d-1)+\frac{1}{4}(m-d)(n-d)\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4}(m-1)(n-1)+\frac{1}{12}\left(d^2-1\right)}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use as in (1) that the $mn$ summands are $d=gcd(m,n)$ copies of the first $\frac{mn}{d}$ summands.
- In (4) we see correspondingly to (2) in groups of $\frac{mn}{d}$ elements $d$ copies of size $\frac{m}{d}\cdot\frac{n}{d}$.
- In (5) we calculate the inner sums using $\sum_{j=0}^n j=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ and $\sum_{j=0}^n j^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$.
- In (6) we calculate the outer sum using the summation formulas as in (5).

Answer (score 2):

The fractional parts depend only on the values modulo $n$ and $m$, respectively.

Since you take $m$ and $n$ relatively prime, you can simply let the two instances of $k$ run through all residue classes modulo $m$ and $n$ independently (Chinese remainder theorem). This reduces your question immediately to the product of the one-variable case for $m$ and $n$.

The one-variable case is a direct consequence of the summation formula for the first $n$ integers.

Edited to add:
This means, of course, that an arbitrary interval is not a very good condition on the pair of residues and there is no reason to expect a general closed expression.

Answer (score 1):

For the relatively prime case. Split the summation into classes $k \equiv 0 \mod m$, $k \equiv 1 \mod m$, $k \equiv 2 \mod m$ and so on. For $k \equiv r \mod m$, and $1 \leq k \leq mn$ each $k$ leaves a distinct remainder when divided by $n$ since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Hence, the summation is $$\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} r}{m} \times \frac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} r}{n} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2m} \frac{m(m-1)}{2n}$$

**EDIT**
Consider the class say $k \equiv r \bmod m$. If $(m,n)=1$, then $r,m+r,2m+r,\cdots,(n-1)m+r$ leave different remainders when divided by $n$. If not then $n | (k_1 - k_2)m$ for some $0 \leq k_1,k_2 <n$. Since $(m,n) = 1$, $n|(k_1-k_2)$. Not possible. Hence, summing all the remainders in the class $k \equiv r \bmod m$ gives us $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Hence, the sum of all the fractional parts is $\displaystyle \frac{n(n-1)}{2m}$.

Comment: This seems good.  Maybe something like this along with a mobius type inclusion exclusion will give the general case.

Comment: @EricNaslund Yes using Chinese remainder theorem sort of argument to get the solution when $(m,n) \neq 1$. I just noticed that Phira has also said the same thing.