# A combinatorics problem refer to this problem?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, problem-solving, fractional-part

If i define $f(m,n)=$ $$\sum_{1\leq k\leq mn}\left\{ \frac{k}{m}\right\} \left\{ \frac{k}{n}\right\} .$$

Then prove $$f(m+n,n) - f(m,n) =\frac{n^2-n}{4}$$
for all $m$ and $n$.

This question came from part of answer from this question: [A sum of fractional parts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140499/a-sum-of-fractional-parts/140517#140517)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $k$ goes from $1$ to $mn$, then the pairs $((k \bmod m),(k \bmod n))$ will meet all cases once.

thus the product is

$$\sum_{1\le k\le m}\left\{\frac{k}{m}\right\}\sum_{1\le t\le n}\left\{\frac{t}{n}\right\}=\frac{m-1}{2}\frac{n-1}{2}\;.$$

Done.

Comment: $\{a\}=a-[a]$, where [a] is the largest integer less than or equal to a.